# O365 Excel and Cells Formatted as TEXT

Tags: microsoft-excel

In the O365 Excel version with Cell formatted as TEXT using a "-" or "+" sign in the text still attempts to add a formula. This did not happen in previous versions I have used. Has anyone figured out how to disable this "feature" with TEXT cells in O365?

Answer (score 0):

Excel accepts `'` as indication that the cell content is TEXT, explicitly.

Try it, type a `'` as first char in the cell. I would expect it to work in O365.
*(It can be used also in LibreOffice, and probably all the free Office version)*

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to Hannu's information. And I think the "-" or "+" sign in Office 365 won't work when the cells are formatted as text. I have tested this in my Office 365 subscription.

[image]